# Getting error : Value of type 'ARReferenceObject' has no member 'merge' : running ScanningApp ARKit2 beta

Tags: swift, swift4, arkit

The error occurs when calling this extension (note: this code was not modified from its original, downloaded from apple)

---

```
extension ARReferenceObject {
    func mergeInBackground(with otherReferenceObject: ARReferenceObject, completion: @escaping (ARReferenceObject?, Error?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let mergedObject = try self.merge(otherReferenceObject)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(mergedObject, nil)
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

has anyone else run into this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the error stack here

Comment: Which Xcode beta are you using? I downloaded the sample app a couple of hours ago and it works like a charm on the latest beta (beta 6 IIRC)

Comment: I only see Xcode beta 5 on the developer's download page.. am I missing something?

Comment: I was running an older version of Xcode beta!  Working now.